# Vue Multiselect: How to send console.log once selection has been made

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Using [Vue Multiselect](http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/), I am trying to send a console.log once I have made a selection. I thought it would work by putting it in the `watch` but it does not work. Where should it be placed. Please see my component below.

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label v-for="topic in topics" class="radio-inline radio-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('http://s3.hubsrv.com/trendsideas.com/profiles/74046767539/photo/3941785781469144249_690x460.jpg')">
      <input type="radio" v-model="internalValue" name="topics_radio" :id="topic.id" :value="topic.name">
      <span class="white-color lg-text font-regular text-center text-capitalize">{{ topic.name }}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      internalValue: this.value,
      topics: []
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get('/vuetopics').then(response => this.topics = response.data);
  },
  watch: {
    internalValue(v){
      this.$emit('input', v);
      console.log('topic has been chosen!!!');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fires [events](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events), so you may catch them.

```
<multiselect ... @select="doSomething" ...>
```

Then add your method

```
...
methods: {
    doSomething(selectedOption, id) {
        console.log(selectedOption);
    }
}
```

Make sure you implemented vue-multiselect correctly, I don't see the component in your code.

Comment: <multiselect ... v-model="something" ...> and then you can watch "something" to subscribe to changes.

Comment: Thanks, you were right the example I used here does not utilise multiselect. This answer will help on my other components that do.

Comment: Link to the documentation is broken, there is the the new one : https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events

Comment: Thanks @TyrionGraphiste I'm gonna fix it ;)